# Java: Rotate bufferedimage without affecting the image's position

Tags: java, rotation

```
g.rotate(1, objSize/2, objSize/2);
g.drawImage(frames[count], (int)x, (int)y, null);
g.rotate(-1, objSize/2, objSize/2);
```

This is the coding I used to rotate one image which is the Player that you can move, the player rotates fine but it moves like the whole world has rotated (if you know what I mean) so I need to know a way to rotate the player without affecting the movement/position, I searched around google and couldn't find the right answer, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Create a method that rotates the player and pass the values which are required to move the player.. (i mean abstact a class out of the code u wrote to rotate and just pass required values to method)..

this will not change the values and Do the work..

:)